# Displaying records grouped by month and year in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I need to sort my records by date (month & year) as displayed on my asp.net page;
Any ideas / suggestions would be helpful.

This is the code I currently have

```
                <table width="40%" border="0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
                    <tr><td><asp:Label ID="lblGridHeader" CssClass="TextFont" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvInvoiceList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true">
                                <columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="File Type">
                                        <ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="imgFileType" ImageUrl="images/Icon_Pdf.gif" NavigateUrl='<%# SetNavigateUrl(Eval("Name")) %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                  <asp:boundfield datafield="Name" headertext="Invoice #"/>
                                  <asp:boundfield datafield="LastWriteTime" headertext="Date Modified"/>
                                </columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

**Code behind:**

```
    If files.Count > 0 Then
        Dim DT As New DataTable()
        DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))
        DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("LastWriteTime", System.Type.GetType("System.String")))

        Dim strCurrentMonth As String = ""

        For Each f As FileInfo In files
            If (MonthName(f.LastWriteTime.Month) <> strCurrentMonth) And (strCurrentMonth <> "") Then
                gvInvoiceList.DataSource = DT
                gvInvoiceList.DataBind()

                lblGridHeader.Text = MonthName(f.LastWriteTime.Month) & " - " & Year(f.LastWriteTime)
            Else
                lblGridHeader.Text = MonthName(f.LastWriteTime.Month) & " - " & Year(f.LastWriteTime)
            End If

            Dim Row1 As DataRow
            Row1 = DT.NewRow()
            Row1("Name") = f.Name
            Row1("LastWriteTime") = f.LastWriteTime
            DT.Rows.Add(Row1)

            strCurrentMonth = MonthName(f.LastWriteTime.Month)
        Next
        gvInvoiceList.DataSource = DT
        gvInvoiceList.DataBind()
    Else
        lblSummary.Text = "No data to show."
    End If
```

Comment: Include some details about how the records are grouped. It's tough to visualize what you need without knowing what the data looks like.

Comment: I don't understand why you need a loop. If the database is doing the grouping for you, can't you just display the results of the query?

Comment: I need to display them in seperate blocks with a header of "Month Year"

Comment: This might require a `<span>` tag on the client side if I am correct and then create an instance of the gridview dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a Repeater. Something *like* this (you should be able to adapt it easily):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_RowDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="color: White; background-color: #3A4F63;" visible="false"
                id="headerTable">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <asp:Label ID="headerTitle" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px; background-color: #3A4F63; color: White;">
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        Directory Name
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        Creation Time
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- These are the actual data items -->
            <!-- Bind to your specific properties i.e. Invoice #, file type, etc. -->
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDirName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DirectoryName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCreationTime" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CreationTime") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

On Code Behind, the `OnItemDataBound` looks like this:

```
Private month As Integer = -1
Private year As Integer = -1
Protected Sub rpt_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    'Binding to FileInfo objects. You are binding to DataTable. Adjust it accordingly
        If month <> TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, FileInfo).CreationTime.Month OrElse year <> TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, FileInfo).CreationTime.Year Then
            month = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, FileInfo).CreationTime.Month
            year = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, FileInfo).CreationTime.Year
            e.Item.FindControl("headerTable").Visible = True
            TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("headerTitle"), Label).Text = "Files for " & TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, FileInfo).CreationTime.ToShortDateString()
        Else
            e.Item.FindControl("headerTable").Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The way I bound my data to the repeater is like this:

```
Dim fi As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo("C:\").GetFiles().OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CreationTime).ToArray()
rpt.DataSource = fi
rpt.DataBind()
```

Produces this output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. Though, where are you sorting this by date?

Comment: @DotNetRookie yes, you need to if you want to be able to construct the headers correctly. Doing this in a DataTable is simple, if that's your concern. You can simply do dataTable.DefaultView.Sort or use Linq (as I did).

Comment: No, your way works. I just need to sort the records inverse from what you got (and group them by month and year).... other than that it works great

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out (OrderByDescending) change to OrderBy

Comment: @DotNetRookie I did `OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.CreationTime).ToArray()`, because I thought showing the most recent ones first was more useful; if you need the inverse, just do `OrderBy` instead of `OrderByDescending`. Ex: `OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreationTime).ToArray()`. That's of course if you use Linq. If you use dataTable.DefaultView.Sort you can do `.Sort("CreationTime ASC");`

Comment: Hi Icarus .... can you possibly take a look at this post (it's part two of my obstacle) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761280/retreive-datatable-column-value-in-rpt-rowdatabound-sub-in-asp-net

Comment: @DotNetCookie posted my answer on your other question. Take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET content that you have should be put in a `Repeater`. The `files` that you have should then be grouped by the month and date. So basically you will end up with a parent-child list. The parent which is the group of files will be bound to the `Repeater`, and the children which are the files belonging to that group will be bound the the `GridView` in the `Repeater`.

### The ASP.NET content

The ASP.NET content would be something along this line. Take note the `gvInvoiceList` `DataSource` property is bound to `InvoiceList`, a property of the group that I came up with (which you will see in the code below) that will have a list of files belonging to the group.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repInvoiceGroups" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table width="40%" border="0" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <tr><td><asp:Label ID="lblGridHeader" CssClass="TextFont" 
                               Text='<%# Eval("MonthYear", "{0:MMMM yyyy}") %>' 
                               runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvInvoiceList" runat="server" 
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" 
                                  DataSource='<%# Eval("InvoiceList") %>'>
                        <columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderText="File Type">
                                <ItemTemplate><asp:HyperLink ID="imgFileType" ImageUrl="images/Icon_Pdf.gif" NavigateUrl='<%# SetNavigateUrl(Eval("Name")) %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                          <asp:boundfield datafield="Name" headertext="Invoice #"/>
                          <asp:boundfield datafield="LastWriteTime" headertext="Date Modified"/>
                        </columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

### The code-behind

As for the code, I'm not fluent on using `DataTable` to have the parent-child relationship needed for the ASP.NET structure that I used for my answer, but it should be easily doable using normal classes. And I'm also not fluent on using VB.NET, so excuse my example which will be using C#, which I guess you should able to convert it quite easily to VB.NET.

I'm using `Linq` to do the grouping and an anonymous class to have the parent-child relationship for this, so the code is rather short.

```
repInvoiceGroups.DataSource = files
    .GroupBy(f => f.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM"))
    .Select(g => new { 
        MonthYear = DateTime.ParseExact(g.Key, "yyyy-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
        InvoiceList = g.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime) })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.MonthYear);
repInvoiceGroups.DataBind();
```

p/s: The code was written in a text editor and untested. Let me know if you face any errors. :)

Comment: This looks good but it won't generate the header that he wants for every group (month-year) of files.

Comment: @Icarus, yes it will (at least it supposed to, I didn't test it). That's what `Text='<%# Eval("MonthYear", "{0:MMMM yyyy}") %>'` is for.